# Ajax callback not working with 'language_select' in drupal 8 forms

Tags: forms, 8, ajax

I'm trying to implement an ajax callback whenever language gets changed. Following code I have used:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
$langcode = $from_database->lid;
$form['langcode'] = array(
           '#title' => $this->t('Language'),
           '#type' => 'language_select',
           '#default_value' => !empty($langcode) ? $langcode : $language,
           '#languages' => Language::STATE_ALL,
           '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => ::ajax_example_autocheckboxes_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'checkboxes-div',

       ) ,
       );

$form['checkboxes_fieldset'] = array(
  '#title' => t("Generated Checkboxes"),
  // The prefix/suffix provide the div that we're replacing, named by
  // #ajax['wrapper'] above.
  '#prefix' => '<div id="checkboxes-div">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#description' => t('This is where we get automatically generated    checkboxes'),
 );
}

function ajax_example_autocheckboxes_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['checkboxes_fieldset'];
}
```

But ajax callback is not working. Suggest a way to implement ajax on language select.

Comment: can you paste your full code on ajax callback what are you trying to achieve??

Comment: @ShreyaShetty full code is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a container. It works for me:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    $current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $user_preferred_langcode = $current_user->getPreferredLangcode();

    // The status messages that will contain any form errors.
    $form['status_messages'] = [
     '#type' => 'status_messages',
     '#weight' => -10,
    ];

    $form['title'] = [
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'h2',
      '#value' => t('Change Language'),
    ];

    $form['preferred_langcode'] = [
      '#type' => 'language_select',
      '#languages' => LanguageInterface::STATE_CONFIGURABLE,
      '#default_value' => $user_preferred_langcode,
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'languageCallback'],
        'event' => 'change',
        'wrapper' => 'language-wrapper',
      ],
    ];

    $form['language_wrapper'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => ['id' => 'language-wrapper'],
    ];

    $preferred_langcode = $form_state->getValue('preferred_langcode');

   if(empty($preferred_langcode) || $user_preferred_langcode == 
$preferred_langcode) {
      $form['language_wrapper']['default_language'] = [
        '#type' => 'html_tag',
        '#tag' => 'p',
        '#value' => $this->t('Your Current Language'),
      ];
    }

    $form_state->setCached(FALSE);

    return $form;
  }

  public function languageCallback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['language_wrapper'];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**If using a non-trivial form element like `language_select`, you need to supply the AJAX `event` attribute.** This is because [`RenderElement::preRenderAjaxForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!RenderElement.php/function/RenderElement%3A%3ApreRenderAjaxForm) knows default `event` values for very basic field types only. This also holds for Drupal 9.

```
$form['preferred_langcode'] = [
  '#title' => $this->t('Language'),
  '#type' => 'language_select',
  '#languages' => LanguageInterface::STATE_CONFIGURABLE,
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => [$this, 'languageCallback'],
    'event' => 'change',
  ],
];
```